# Applying for the BC PNP Tech Pilot Program While Working Remotely

Tags: canada, express-entry, pr

I'm a student in BC, Canada, recently I got a job offer for a company for an IT position (DevOps Consultant), the company is located in both Ottawa and Toronto, but it doesn't have any offices in BC, so my question is: is it possible to apply for the *BC PNP Tech Pilot* program in this situation?, I know of someone who was invited to apply under similar conditions.